# Change collapsing to button

Tags: jquery

I've got a list that collapses and expands once you click on it. See this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYxZJP

How can I change it so that if you click the red button, it collapses?

```
$('li > ul').hide();

//activate class "expanded"
$('li > .expanded ~ ul').show('normal');

$('li > a').click(function() {
    //hide everything
    $(this).find('ul').hide();

    //toggle next ul
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').next('ul').toggle('normal');
});
```

Comment: Most users won't want to click an unknown link in a question. Consider instead taking a screenshot of your issue and linking to that image on a known and trusted image site, like imgur or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click handler to the `.cats-toggle` elements to collapse the `<ul>` that precedes it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.cats-toggle', event => {
  $(event.currentTarget).prev('ul').hide('normal');
});
```

https://codepen.io/neagle/pen/barWYM?editors=1111